# Make MediaPlayer load from URL only

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I would like the MediaPlayer to load the video from URL and not to search the local files - is it possible?

I receive the error message for the video from the external server:

```
MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException happend 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://www....video.mp4
...
Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

The error appears for the line:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(VideoActivity.this,videoUri);
```

Important: eventually the app loads and displays correctly the video (dispite the fact that the error appears)!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411792/android-sdk-media-player-video-from-url

Comment: try this .hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you, it solved my question